# How can I create a dynamic number of DefaultMessageListenerContainer MDPojos in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jms

I need to create a variable number of these based on a configuration value, the intention is to have multiple consumers where each corresponds to a physical resource that can only be used by one thing at a time to process the message.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a container that manages multiple instances of DefaultMessageListenerContainer(s) which it creates based off of a prototypical instance if the listener.  Based on a system property (a # value), a number of listeners are created and the queues they listen to are numeric "my.Queue" + ordinal number.  This could obviously be modified to look up the queue names if necessary.  That being said, this is not a dynamically expanding/contracting list of listeners. They are created at the beginning, although I think you could use this as a starting point to make it more dynamic if you wish to.

I wrote a pretty rudimentary unit test and a very rudimentary implementation (no multithreading taken into consideration), and it appears to work.

The maven project can be downloaded here -
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7812537/StackOverflowMultipleListeners.zip

BTW - there's an interesting thread here - http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=69604

I think there could be a way to do this by extending a generic bean factory but i'm not sure what your requirements are.